# $scope is updated in view and not in controller for angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jquery-select2

I have a scope defined in a controller as mentioned below :

Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select2']);

app.controller('MyCtrl',
  [
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    '$timeout',
    function ($scope, $, $timeout) {
      $scope.data = {};
       $scope.countries = [{
          name : 'India', code : 'IA'
        }, {
          name : 'Israel', code : 'IS'
        }];

        $scope.selectedCountries = [
          'IA'
        ];

        $scope.$watch('selectedCountries', function(newValue, oldValue) {
           console.log ('data');
    });
]);
```

view looks like this :

```
<select
        ui-select2
        multiple
        ng-model="selectedCountries"
        data-placeholder="Choose or Search for countries"
        name="countries"
        style="width:200px;">
        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now when the value changes in controller using select dropdown, the value changes are reflected in view.  But the watch is never called, as the scope is not changed.  Any idea why the scope is not updating ?

Comment: can you show the view?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: This could be linked to the view not actually touching the $scope.selectedCountries variable. Could you please show us the complete code to track the issue ?

Comment: I am using select2 plugin of angular js, it reflects the changes on view but not in controller.

Comment: updated my code, i hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

For watching collections pass `true` as the third parameter to $watch, so it becomes:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCountries', function(...) {...}, true);
```

This makes $digest step through the collection recursively instead of just doing a reference check.

Alternatively if you have a deep structure and you only need to know if the bottom level has changed (i.e. added or removed elements) you can use $watchCollection instead of $watch.

UPDATE: Working Plunker (works without deep $watch()): http://www.plnkr.co/edit/VaWBq9?p=preview

Comment: $watchCollection() acts like `$watch('...', function() { ...}, true)` -- in other words, it does a "shallow" comparison: for arrays this means watching the array items, for object maps this means watching the properties.  A shallow compare will detect if elements have been added or removed, but it will also detect if any items values have changed.  Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/izSyHZjDbXDZvA016ZJ8?p=preview) showing the latter.

Comment: @insomiac Seems select:multiple replaces the array each time rather than splicing it so it works without the deep $watch: http://www.plnkr.co/edit/VaWBq9?p=preview
Your code seems to work fine here.

@MarkRajcok `$watchCollection(..)` is shallow, but `$watch(.., .., true)` is deep. The both will see if contents of the object or array have changed but only the latter will see if the content inside that content has changed.